# How to extract recipient from email

Tags: c#, exchange-server, mailenable

I'm trying to find out how to extract a recipients email address from an email which we are blind copied in on.

We work on Windows servers with C#/Asp.Net. Currently we have MailEnable on the server, however this isn't a restricting factor, should we need to change it out.

Anyone done it or know a site that covers it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<

Why are you trying to do this ? eg auditing, data leakage etc

A BCC won't be visible on the Message that was received by the intended recipients so you won't be able to extract it from that. On the source server where the message was sent (or the first hub/mta it passed through) if its Exchange then you can take the Internet MessageId of the Message and Search the Exchange Message Tracking logs to determine who the message was sent to and then compare that to the recipients of the Message and infer the BCC (or forwards) on a Message. A transport Agent could do this from a application perspective where for a source message you have access to the Microsoft.Exchange.Transport.RecipientP2Type in the EnvelopeRecipient https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.data.transport.enveloperecipient.properties(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: Sorry, its taken so long to come back. Here's why I need it. A third party sends an email out to clients when they buy something. I want them to BCC me in, so that I can create follow up actions - I don't need the BCC because it's always the same but I do need the recipient address.